# Calling a method from viewcontroller in the appdelegate does not change the text on the Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

Every time when I launch the app, I want to change the text on the screen. The method is called but text does not change.

myAppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:-1];
    viewController *object = [[viewController alloc] init];
    [object methodA];
}
```

viewController.m

```
-(void)methodA{
    //Create an URL pointing to your plist
    NSURL *plistURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"myPlist" withExtension: @"plist"];
    //Read the plist from the application bundle into an array object.
    NSArray *stringsArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL: plistURL];
    //Create a random index into the array
    NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random_uniform(stringsArray.count);
    //Fetch the string at that random index
    NSString *randomString = stringsArray[randomIndex];
    //Set some label's text to the random string.
    _myLabel.text = randomString;
    NSLog(@"methodA");
```

}

I get "methodA" in my log.

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `viewController`. Don't do that. Get a reference to the existing view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
yourViewController *object = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"id"];
[object methodA];
```

Replace `MainStoryboard` with your storyboard name and `id` with your view controller id. You can set the id in your storyboard. Last replace `yourViewController` with your view controller.(Do not forget to import it).

Comment: @ArdaKeskiner Are you using storyboards?

Comment: @ArdaKeskiner Did you replace "MainStoryboard" with your storyboard name?